# MAAS option not appearing in the quickstart menu

Tags: juju, maas

I have a problem with the quickstart of juju.

When I do `juju-quickstart -i`, it doesn't appear MAAS as a environment.

Comment: Can you edit your post to add the Juju, quickstart, and os versions.